# How to handle redux master and detail

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux for an api-centric application and having trouble with the concept of master and detail retrievals.

Say I get may master list with a redux-thunk action like this:

```
// action:
export const fetchItems = params => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({type: FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST});
  let response = await api.fetchItems(params);
  dispatch({type: FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload: normalize(response, schema)});
}
```

Then I want to drill down on a single item that I retrieve like this:

```
export const fetchItem = id = async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({type: FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM_REQUEST});
  let response = await api.fetchItem(id);
  dispatch({type: FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM_SUCCESS, payload: normalize(response, schema)});
}
```

They both end up in my reducer in the same way -

```
const reducer = (state, {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type) {
    case FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS:
    case FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: payload.result.data,
        byId: payload.entities.item,
        error: null,
        fetching: false
      };
    case FETCH_ITEMS_REQUEST:
    case FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM_REQUEST:
      // how do I/should I separate fetching id=1 vs fetching all items??
      return { ...state, fetching: true, error: null };
    case FETCH_ITEMS_FAILURE:
    case FETCH_SINGLE_ITEM_FAILURE:
      // how do I/should I separate fetching id=1 vs fetching all items for error??
      return { ...state, fetching: false, error: payload };

  }
}
```

I don't think I should be sharing the fetching and error as variables for the single item and all items.

I started down the road of hashing errors and fetching status by id for the single item, but it's kind of ugly.

Should the single item be moved into its own reducer? In which case should it not follow the allIds/byId pattern? I don't think I want to do that because I want to introduce caching so I can check if the record exists before querying the API.

How do I structure my redux reducers for both many and the single record?

Comment: Hi, why the down vote?

Comment: I'd recommend to keep the "list" and "by id" concepts in separate reducers. This simplifies the action names and many other things. Both could have a FETCH_SUCCESS for example, and you don't have to work the differentiation into all the variable names. Also improves testing, readability, and error handling. Separation of concerns. You can still have caching of course, a selector for the "by id" state can tell you if items exist. Even when "drilling down" and fetching all items of a list, you can use the selector (via getState in thunks) to skip the cached items.

Comment: @timotgl I agree thanks. It was kind of a dumb question in hindsight

Comment: I don't think it's a dumb question at all. Sometimes several drafts are necessary when fleshing out an architecture, and the react+redux world leaves many possibilities to do things inefficiently.